# Can i change font on facebook comment box plugin at run time

Tags: javascript, iphone, css, facebook, uiwebview

- > i would like to change the font name and color on facebook comment box

> plugin at runtime in uiwebview. I have to use javascript ? if yes what
>   kind of script code should i use.
>
> - Please help me and i will appreciate all the times.
>     ![enter image description here][1]
>
> I cannot post the image.
>   please http://www.mybloggertricks.com/2011/06/add-facebook-comments-box-to-blogger.html check this link 
>   I would like to change the font on runtime in uiwebview.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change anything except light or dark theme. Additionally even if you find a way to do it, it's against the facebook policy.

Comment: I thougt so... but it's strange. We should be able to change ANYTHING, CSS concerning.
I did try; but, really, I couldn't. :-(